# Total Mystery: simple RegExp code only working on certain pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stumped. A client asked to change the color of the star at the end of each of the articles on his site.

So easy!!!

This code:

```
$('.center-col p:contains("✭")').each(function(){
  $(this).html(
    $(this).html().replace('✭','<span class=\'light-purple\'>✭</span>')
  );
});
```

aught to do it. But no.

It works fine on some pages (e.g. [this one](http://johnryle.com/?article=a-first-blast-of-the-hooter-against-the-monstrous-regiment-of-cyclists) and [this one](http://johnryle.com/?article=a-dead-shark-in-the-face-of-the-public)) but refuses to work on others (e.g. [this one](http://johnryle.com/?article=to-conserve-you-must-transform) or [this one](http://johnryle.com/?article=abuses-of-the-laws-of-war-in-sudan)).

All articles are using an identical Wordpress template, and I can't for the life of me find any differences between the articles. I even tried looping through every p tag

```
$('p').each(function(){
  $(this).html(
  $(this).html().replace('✭','<span class=\'light-purple\'>✭</span>')
  );
});
```

and still the same result.

Anyone who can solve this mystery is effing man!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using two different star characters. The character which you're missing is `★` (char code 9733) whereas the character you're searching for is `✭` (char code 10029) - they look nearly identical (possibly identical) but they are different Unicode values.

To fix, either use the same star on each page or adjust your regex to include both stars.

Comment: Oh man... thank you. I had ruled that out because when I tried contains(&#10029;) and contains(&#9733;) it didn't work. I realize now that it needed to be the unicode character rather than the html character. Thanks again!